# App stops when click back to previous screen

Tags: ios, uitableview, crash, back

I'm filling a tableview with data from a server. I fill it well, but I have a function to display the details of each row in another screen, but when I push back, the app Crash, but I don't know why!!

This is my function:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    NSUInteger i, totalNumberOfItems = [gestiones count];
    NSUInteger newNumberOfItemsToDisplay = MIN(totalNumberOfItems, numberOfItemsToDisplay + kNumberOfItemsToAdd);
    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (i=numberOfItemsToDisplay; i<newNumberOfItemsToDisplay; i++) {
        [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
    }

    numberOfItemsToDisplay = newNumberOfItemsToDisplay;

    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    if (numberOfItemsToDisplay == totalNumberOfItems) {
        [tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    }
    [tableView endUpdates];

    // Scroll the cell to the top of the table

    NSIndexPath *scrollPointIndexPath;

    if (newNumberOfItemsToDisplay < totalNumberOfItems) {
        scrollPointIndexPath = indexPath;
    } else {
        scrollPointIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:totalNumberOfItems-1 inSection:0];
    }

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 200000000), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:scrollPointIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    });

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}else{
    Gestion *ges = [gestiones objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    DetalleGestionViewController *vcc = [[DetalleGestionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetalleGestionViewController" bundle:nil];
    vcc.gestion = ges;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vcc animated:YES];

    NUEVA_GESTION = YES;

    [gestiones removeAllObjects];
}
```

}

With "NUEVA_GESTION" I prepare the app to reload the table data.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Declare `DetalleGestionViewController *vcc` as a class variable in your .h file or under category, it will solve your problem.  This issue is bcos your controller deallocated due to ARC enabled when you push back.

Comment: Ok, thanks I'll review it.